# How do I map numbers in C# like with map in Arduino?

Tags: c#, arduino

Is there a function like Arduino's [map](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/map) in C#?

Comment: The link you provided also contains the function implementation, I think the easiest thing would be to just port it to C#.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that there was an implementation until you actually pointed it out.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do it with an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) (for `decimal` for example):

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static decimal Map (this decimal value, decimal fromSource, decimal toSource, decimal fromTarget, decimal toTarget)
    {
        return (value - fromSource) / (toSource - fromSource) * (toTarget - fromTarget) + fromTarget;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
decimal res = 2.Map(1, 3, 0, 10);
// res will be 5
```

Comment: There is an syntax error (closing paren) in your last line of code.

Answer (score 7):

```
private static int map(int value, int fromLow, int fromHigh, int toLow, int toHigh) 
{
    return (value - fromLow) * (toHigh - toLow) / (fromHigh - fromLow) + toLow;
}
```