# While double Y increase from -10 to 10, make double X decrease from 500 to 0

Tags: c#

I have an issue with one moving element on my webapp. There is a `double y`value which can be from `-10 to 10`. Then I have a `double tope` which can be from `0 to 500`, which represents position from top of an absolute element.

Both values are relative to each other. So when `y` is increasing `tope` is decreasing. Problem is I cannot change initial `y = -10` value, otherwise I would just make it from 1 to 20. So I made some manipulations:

```
 double y = -10 to 10 // comes from function, increases, decreases randomly, but never jumps over numbers
 double ynum = 25; 
 double divy = 250; 
 double tope = 500;

 if(y<0)
        {
            y = y * -1;   //Since y starts at -10, I convert it to 10
            y = y + 10;   // I add 10 to reverse, so 10+10 is 20, or 9+10 is 19 ...
            tope = ynum * y;   // 25x20 first initial tope value is 500px, then lets say 25x19.. dropping
        }
        else  // at some point y reaches positive side and I need to decrease tope value further
        {
            tope = divy / y;
        }
```

All of this works fine. `y` goes from `-10 to 10` and tope goes from `500 to 0`. Except when `y` reaches double values below zero `-0.154.., -0.254.., 0.345 ..` since division/multiplication from fractions are quite different.

I tried to force all fractions to be 1 or 0, but then the moving absolute element looses it's smoothness.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a linear function, that maps [-10, 10] to [500, 0], so

```
tope = a*y + b
```

substituting your conditions:

```
0 = 10a + b => b=-10a
500 = -10a + b
```

Plugin the first to the second:

```
500 = -10a + -10a => a = -500/20 = -25
b = -10a = 250
```

So you just need:

```
tope = -25y + 250
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the steps required to take to the whole range of `y` to get to the target range of `tope`:

```
y   : [10..-10]
tope: [0..500]
```

Subtract 10 to align the first value:

```
y - 10: [0..-20]
tope  : [0..500]
```

Now scale to match the size of the last value:
`500/20 = 25`

```
(y - 10)*25: [0..-500]
tope       : [0..500]
```

Finally negate:

```
-(y - 10)*25: [0..500]
tope        : [0..500]
```

so

```
tope = -(y - 10)*25
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353485/how-do-i-map-numbers-in-c-sharp-like-with-map-in-arduino) question might answer yours. You can map the ranges of values together.

This is copied from the accepted answer:

You can do it with an Extension Method (for decimal for example):

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static decimal Map (this decimal value, decimal fromSource, decimal 
        toSource, decimal fromTarget, decimal toTarget)
    {
        return (value - fromSource) / (toSource - fromSource) * (toTarget - 
            fromTarget) + fromTarget;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
decimal res = 2.Map(1, 3, 0, 10);
// res will be 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Type `double` is signed.
Equation for a straight line is `y = m*x + c` where m is the gradient and c is constant.
Given your end points `A:(500,-10)` and `B:(0,+10)`
Plug the coordinates of B into the equation: `10 = m*0 + c`
Solve: `c = 10`
Plug in A and `c`: `-10 = m*500 + 10`
Solve: `m = -1/25 = -0.04`

Formulae (that work for positive and negative x and y)...

```
y = f(x) = -0.04*x + 10; // y from x
x = f(y) = 25*(10-y); // x from y
```